# How to create a custom credit card payment module in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

I am using magento 1.7 and want to create a custom credit card module for magento 1.7.
How can I code for this.

I am very new with magento and I am trying to create credit card payment method for ICICI bank.

Please guide. Any web link or sample code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below of 2 links which very useful to you to make your own custom extension for payment gateway in magento

just go throw

[magento payment extension](http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/)

or

[create magento payment module](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying @liyakat. Your "magento payment extension" link has been solved my query. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/understanding-payment-gateways) to understand how payment gateways work.
...and [this may help you](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) in creating a payment method

Comment: Thanks for replying @Marius. I tried this magento creating module process. It creates module and displaying also in admin panel but it does not redirect to payment gateway when I process payment. What should be the next step? Please guide.